# How to fix wrong attribute error for Visual Composer Grid Builder?

Tags: plugins, shortcode

Hello I am facing this issue in editing media grid layout of Visual Composer V6.2.2. Below is the error I am getting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Wrong attribute for 'vc_single_image' shortcode. Attribute 'param_name' required in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-wpb-map.php:667

Stack Trace
1.   WPBMap::mutateParam('vc_single_image', Array) /var/www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-vc-mapper.php:204
2.   Vc_Mapper->callElementActivities('vc_single_image') /var/www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-wpb-map.php:926
3.   WPBMap::setElementSettings('vc_single_image') /var/www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-wpb-map.php:345
4.   WPBMap::generateData() /var/www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-wpb-map.php:370
5.   WPBMap::getAllShortCodes() /var/www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/shortcodes/core/class-vc-shortcodes-manager.php:173
6.   Vc_Shortcodes_Manager->buildShortcodesAssets('') /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:287
7.   /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311) in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-wpb-map.php on line 667
```

Any Ideas about this Fix?